# Как написать быстрее SELECT для 7 MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sel_preparat = mysql_query('SELECT prepar_name,city,organ_name,street,pharm_address,pharm_tel,prep_upd,price,new_price,discount,id_user,id_prep_user,ph7.user_id AS USID FROM pharm_copy ph1 
                   LEFT JOIN pharm_preparation_user ph7 ON (ph7.id_pharm=ph1.id_copy_pharm) 
                   LEFT JOIN pharm_user ph2 ON (ph2.user_id=ph7.user_id) 
                   LEFT JOIN pharm_signup ph3 ON (ph3.id_user=ph1.id_pharm) 
                   LEFT JOIN pharm_street ph4 ON (ph4.id_street=ph3.id_street) 
                   LEFT JOIN pharm_region ph5 ON (ph5.id_region=ph4.id_region)  
                   LEFT JOIN pharm_discount ph6 ON (ph6.user_id=ph7.user_id) 
                   WHERE ph2.activ=0 AND ph7.activ=1 AND ph7.prepar_name LIKE "%'.$search.'%"'.$filtr.$filtr1.$filtr2.$filtr3.$filtr4.$temp.$filtr5.$wh_price.' 
                   GROUP BY ph7.prepar_name, ph7.price, ph7.city, ph1.id_pharm ASC '.$asc,$db) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Схему БД в студию...

Answer (score 1):

```
$sel_preparat = mysql_query('SELECT prepar_name,city,organ_name,street,pharm_address,pharm_tel,prep_upd,price,new_price,discount,id_user,id_prep_user,ph7.user_id AS USID FROM pharm_copy ph1 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_preparation_user ph7 ON (ph7.id_pharm=ph1.id_copy_pharm) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_user ph2 ON (ph2.user_id=ph7.user_id) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_signup ph3 ON (ph3.id_user=ph1.id_pharm) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_street ph4 ON (ph4.id_street=ph3.id_street) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_region ph5 ON (ph5.id_region=ph4.id_region)  
               LEFT JOIN pharm_discount ph6 ON (ph6.user_id=ph7.user_id) 
               WHERE ph2.activ=0 AND ph7.activ=1 AND ph7.prepar_name LIKE "%'.$search.'%"'.$filtr.$filtr1.$filtr2.$filtr3.$filtr4.$temp.$filtr5.$wh_price.' 
               GROUP BY ph7.prepar_name, ph7.price, ph7.city, ph1.id_pharm ASC '.$asc,$db) or die(mysql_error());
```

Попробуй из WHERE вынести условия (те, которые можно) выше. Например ph7.activ=1. То есть как-то так:

```
$sel_preparat = mysql_query('SELECT prepar_name,city,organ_name,street,pharm_address,pharm_tel,prep_upd,price,new_price,discount,id_user,id_prep_user,ph7.user_id AS USID FROM pharm_copy ph1 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_preparation_user ph7 ON (ph7.id_pharm=ph1.id_copy_pharm AND ph7.activ=1) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_user ph2 ON (ph2.user_id=ph7.user_id) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_signup ph3 ON (ph3.id_user=ph1.id_pharm) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_street ph4 ON (ph4.id_street=ph3.id_street) 
               LEFT JOIN pharm_region ph5 ON (ph5.id_region=ph4.id_region)  
               LEFT JOIN pharm_discount ph6 ON (ph6.user_id=ph7.user_id) 
               WHERE ph2.activ=0 AND ph7.prepar_name LIKE "%'.$search.'%"'.$filtr.$filtr1.$filtr2.$filtr3.$filtr4.$temp.$filtr5.$wh_price.' 
               GROUP BY ph7.prepar_name, ph7.price, ph7.city, ph1.id_pharm ASC '.$asc,$db) or die(mysql_error());
```

Ну и т.д. по аналогии. Это сократит объем выборки в её процессе и соотв-но ускорит её. Если индексы всё ещё "не повешаны", то повесь, где это нужно. Успехов!

Comment: Спасибо, я постараюсь сделать это